# How to change the title window of a window in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10

I have compiled Lua using [this tutorial](http://lua-users.org/wiki/BuildingLuaInWindowsForNewbies). The compiling went fine, and now I have a folder in C drive named Lua.
Its contents are `bin\lua.exe`, `bin\lua54.dll`, `bin\luac.exe` and a few other files.

I managed to change the icon of it. I found [this link](https://www.discriminator.nl/forum/index.php?topic=801.0) which had a tutorial to change the title of an executable. The only problem is that it was recently compiled, so it doesn't have a String Table value. Is there any other way to change the title?

Comment: What have you tried? We aren't a code writing service, and the Windows API and Devkits are pretty well documented.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it fails to demonstrate the minimum amount of work prior to asking.

Comment: @music3myear I am not asking help with code, I am asking how to edit the title display of an executable. I added that it was just compiled because a program that you download from the internet has a String Table, unlike this program (which only has icon and icon group) And I have tried other tutorials which don't work for me.

Comment: I also mentioned I am new to Stack Exchange, so I do not know any formatting rules for questions.

Comment: This ain't a "new to the site" issue, this is a "there are many resources out there that probably answer your question but you didn't try to find any of them, or if you did you didn't show anything to indicate you did, so we don't know what not to suggest" issue. Also, the rules are laid out in our friendly and convenient Help section.

Comment: Yes, there probably are, but I don't know much about Resource Hacker (and that is the only one I have found so far). So I don't know how to make a String Table (if I did I wouldn't have asked this question.)

Comment: Ok never mind, I just realised making a shortcut to the exe can change the name of the title to the name of the shortcut.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**So to be clear - adding a string table will do nothing unless you write code to read it.**

```
@Echo Off
Echo Two files follow
Echo SetWindowText.bat
Echo This file compiles SetWindowText.vb to SetWindowText.exe using the system VB.NET compiler.
Echo SetWindowText.exe sets the titlebar text for a window
Echo     SetWindowText.exe "OldWindowTitle" "NewWindowTitle"
Echo EG Open notepad and type in a command prompt
Echo     SetWindowText.exe "Untitled - Notepad" "My Window Title"
Echo ----------------------------------------------------------------------
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\vbc.exe" /target:winexe /out:"%~dp0\SetWindowText.exe" "%~dp0\SetWindowText.vb" 
pause
```

---

```
Imports System
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports Microsoft.Win32

Public Module MyApplication  


Public Declare UNICODE Function FindWindowW Lib "user32" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As IntPtr

Public Declare UNICODE Function SetWindowTextW Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal lpString As String) As Integer

Sub Main()
On Error Resume Next
Dim CmdLine As String
Dim Ret as Integer
Dim A() as String
Dim hwindows as IntPtr

CmdLine = Command()
If Left(CmdLine, 2) = "/?" Then
    MsgBox("Usage:" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "SetText ""OldWindowTitle"" ""NewWindowTitle""")
Else
    A = Split(CmdLine, Chr(34), -1, vbBinaryCompare)
    hwindows = FindWindowW(vbNullString, A(1))
    Ret = SetWindowTextW(hwindows,  A(3))
End If
End Sub
End Module
```

---

Generally the default window title is the exe file's name. Programs tend to change it like above, either through Windows API direct or through their language forms package indirectly.

If you were writing international software you would put the title in the string table and read it at runtime then change the title. So different languages would use different tables.

Comment: Thanks for the help but I kind of wanted a permanent solution. Thanks anyway! I figured I will just make a shortcut to the file that automatically runs it and changes the title.

Comment: I went to the LUA web site but really can't tell what type of program it is, ie - console or graphical (the two types of windows programs). I couldn't find out if it supports API calls or COM.

Comment: it is a command-line program that you have to compile. You can change the program logo but I am not sure how to permanently change the title bar. that is why I asked this question.